# Understanding a PHP RESTful API

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, rest

I have the following XAMPP project structure

`xampp/htdocs/project`
`xampp/htdocs/project/index.php`
`xampp/htdocs/project/api/index.php`

I also use the folowing .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/index\.php(/|$)
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I make an Ajax request to api/, I get the results from api/index.php
But what if I want to get the examples for api/users/? or api/users/5 where 5 is the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you are done, you'll have quite a lot of rewrite entries.  But here's one that should do what you want with respect to users:

```
# /users/{id}
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9A-Za-z_\.-\@]+)$    users.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

or, if you want everything to pass through index:

```
# /users/{id}
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9A-Za-z_\.-\@]+)$    index.php?userid=$1 [QSA]
```

and, if you need to differentiate by request type (POST, GET, PUT, etc):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ="post" [NC]
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$  index.php?id=$1&method=add_user [QSA]
```

Comment: Isn't there a more generic approach then? like, redirect everything to index.php regardless, and from there on handle the request myself.

Comment: @hermann - if there is, it's above my pay grade.  I don't know of one.  You have to tell it *specifically* which parameters you are expecting.  This can get complicated.  And the above can be modified to address all to index.  See the edit I'm making now...

Comment: please look at tdammers' answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795228/rest-web-services?rq=1
I'm just not sure how to do this.

Comment: His answer doesn't actually address the htaccess aspect, which is what your question is.  His answer is more geared towards the php files that will handle the request.  You can have them all go through index.php, but you'll need to identify and handle the parameters in the url with your .htacess file, *assuming* you want to use pretty urls like that.

Comment: so if I end up with 50 different files I'm also gonna have 50 different rules? would this be considered a necessary evil, or a practice to be avoid?

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but the person I learned from *is* an expert, and that was the solution I was taught.  The .htaccess file for a (complicated) API we developed has 17 rules in it.  For completeness sake, I'm making one more edit with an example of how to differentiate based on the request type (POST, GET, PUT, etc)

Answer (score 2):

First rewrite all to the single point ie. index.php, except the real existing assets, then introduce some kind of routing or a router component.

```
class Route{

private $routes = array();

public function addRoute($method, $url, $action){
    $this->routes[] = array('method' => $method, 
                          'url' => $url, 
                          'action' => $action
                          );
}

public function route(){
    $requestUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $httpRequestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    foreach($this->routes as  $route) {
        //convert route's variables with a regular expression
        $pattern = "@^" . preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($route['url'])) . "$@D";
        $matches = array();

        if($httpRequestMethod == $route['method'] && preg_match($pattern, $requestUrl, $matches)) {
            // remove the first match and just keet the extracted parameters
            array_shift($matches);
            // call specified controller's actions with the paramaters
            return call_user_func_array($route['action'], $matches);
        }
    }
}
}

class MyController{
    public function myAction($param)
    {
        //$this->render(), return Response(); etc. etc.
        echo $param; 
    }
}


class MyController2{
    public function myAction2($param)
    {
        //$this->render(), return Response(); etc. etc.
        echo $param; 
    }
}

$route = new Route();

$route->addRoute('GET', '/', 'MyController::myAction');
$route->addRoute('GET', '/resources/:id', 'MyController2::myAction2');

$route->route();
```

Also, check http://toroweb.org/